# select2 : createSearchChoice Cannot read property 'id' of null

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

```
createSearchChoice: function (term,data) {

                        if ($(data).filter(function() {
                            return this.text.toString().localeCompare(term) === 0;
                        }).length === 0) {
                            if (/\S+#\S+/g.test(term)) {
                                return {
                                    id : term,
                                    text : term
                                };
                            } else {
                                return null;
                            }
                        }
                    },
```

I am provinding new tag option based on some format if format deosnt match i am returning null,

but select2 createSearchChoice method expecting **return id**, but if i return id it will create that tag on dropdown, which i want to avoid,

is there any way we can avoid new tag if it doesn't match my criteria.